# Why my navigation items are not visible into my bootstrap navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, logic

I have one website onto the live server, but I am facing a problem into the navigation bar. The nav Items just blink for a second or two and they disappers. Why this is happening?
I have made the UI using bootstrap.
you may visit the website as under [www.mathrubhumigroup.com](https://www.mathrubhumigroup.com). Please inspect the site and tell me why this is behaving oddly (specially the navigation bar items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation has disappeared because the collapse class has been applied to the navigation container, and it has the style visibility: collapse, that's why it has disappeared.

If you remove the CSS or override it with new CSS, the issue is resolved.

**CSS:**
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {visibility: visible !important;}